# How to draw arrow outside of a diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to draw this diagram

[image]

I tried this

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r} \arrow[swap]{d} \arrow[bend left]{dr}& B \arrow{d} \\
C \arrow{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

but what I get is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the bending angle, but it is arguably easier to use the `in` and `out` keys, and to adjust the `looseness`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r} \arrow[swap]{d} \arrow[out=45,in=45,looseness=1.6]{dr}& B \arrow{d} \\
C \arrow{r} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]